# Can't get UserManager from OwinContext in apicontroller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm following a Microsoft sample to implement email validation with Identity 2.0.0

I'm stuck at this part

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
   get
   {
      return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
   }
   private set
   {
      _userManager = value;
   }
}
```

This works in an `controller` but `HttpContext` doesn't contain any `GetOwinContext` method in an **ApiController**.

So I tried `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()` but the method `GetUserManager` doesn't exist.

I can't figure out a way to get the `UserManager` I build in **Startup.Auth.cs**

```
// For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //Configure the db context, user manager and role manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create); 
    ...
}
```

this line

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

calls the following function to configure the `UserManager`

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
     var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
     //Configure validation logic for usernames
     manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
     {
         AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
         RequireUniqueEmail = true
     };

     // Configure user lockout defaults
     manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
     manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
     manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

     manager.EmailService = new EmailService();

     var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
     if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
     {
         manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
     }
     return manager;
}
```

How can I access this `UserManager` in an `ApiController`?

Comment: Do you use any DI-framework?

Comment: What do you mean that the GetOwinContext() doesn't exists in your ApiController? Is it null or empty?

Comment: Sorry. The method doesn't exist

Comment: Look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I really misunderstood your question earlier. You are just missing some using statements, I think.

The `GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()` is in  `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`.

So try add this part:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; // Maybe this one too

var manager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager<User>>();
```

Comment: That's what I used to do but the options I add in the create function are not there.

Comment: Would it be safer overall to use : System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager....

Comment: @RobertAchmann I can't see why that should be safer or even better because `HttpContext.Current` is a _static_ property returning the current `HttpContext` for the thread.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually answer the question as `HttpContext` is not accessible in an ApiController. Using the extension in `System.Net.Http` from `System.Web.Http.Owin.dll`  works fine from the nuget plugin - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin

Comment: The manager returns null for me, do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 28):

This extension method may be a better solution if you want to unit test your controllers.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin;

public static IOwinContext GetOwinContext(this HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var context = request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
    if (context != null)
    {
        return HttpContextBaseExtensions.GetOwinContext(context.Request);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
   get
   {
      return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
   }
   private set
   {
      _userManager = value;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer and should be the accepted one.  Does not rely on HttpContext.Current.

Comment: I totally agree, the `HttpContext.Current` introduces a dependency to `System.Web`, which is not available in self-hosted scenarios.  `Request.GetOwinContext()` is injected, therefore allowing for test-ability.  The latter is neither.

Comment: BTW... `Request.GetOwinContext()` is defined in the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin nuget package

Comment: This helped me avoid exceptions that were getting thrown when i would use `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()`. This is much better.

Comment: Agree this is the better answer as it avoids potential exception issues around `HttpContext.Current`. You can then just write `Request?.GetOwinContext()`.

Comment: I'm getting "The given key was not present in the dictionary" error when using like this, because Request is returning null because there is no property in request as "MS_HttpContext". I tried with "MS_OwinContext" or "MS_RequestContext", in these cases context returns null

Answer (score 7):

This single line of code saved my day...

```
       var manager = 
       new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

You can use it within a controller action to get an instance of UserManager.