# How could I use ApplicationUserManager in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unity-container, user-management

I have created a controller named `ProfileContoller` in my application. 
In this controller I need to creat an instance of `ApplicationUserManager` however I don't know how to create a new instance of it. I've tried code below:

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager = Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

but I got this error:

> The name `Current` does not exist in the current context

My first question is how could I do this? I'll acces this line of code:

```
return View(await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username));
```

I also use an `UnityContainer`. My second question about this is: could I also register the `ApplicationUserManager` associated with the interface `IUser` or `IUserStore`<sup>1</sup>.

---

**Update:**

Later I've found there is something like this:

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager = UserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Bit it give me this error:

> Non-invocable member `UserManager<TUser>` cannot be used like a method.

With this extra "user manager", I can't see the I can't see the wood for the trees. So once more can you explain me what all the "user managers" mean and what they are used for?

---

<sub>**Notes:**

<sup>1</sup> I don't know the difference between this two so if you'll, can you explane this too?</sub>

Comment: Do you have the correct using statements? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001245/cant-get-usermanager-from-owincontext-in-apicontroller

Comment: um regarding the `cannot be used like a method` -- are you missing the `new` keyword? -- It really does look like you're trying to invoke a type like it's a method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
using System.Web;  //make sure you have this using

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userManager == null && HttpContext == null)
            {
                return new ApplicationUserManager(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
            }
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the type `ApplicationUserManager` come from? -- It doesn't exist by default; do you have a class named this somewhere? -- Also your `_userManager` cache value never gets set in this case, perhaps instead of just returning the value you should set it first, and then return it as a second step.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked at this in VS so am not 100% however the error message you are getting

> The name Current does not exist in the current context

could just be down to the fact that current is part of the http context

try

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public ProfileController()
    {
        _userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
```

So the change here is that _userManager is being declared but not set.
We are then setting it in the constructor for the class.

Comment: No I'm sorry. Now I've got this error **A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property `Controller.HttpContext`**

Comment: I have edited with an update that I think will help.

Comment: I doesn't work also. I've this error **'IOwinContext' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserManager' and no extension method 'GetUserManager' accepting a first argument of type 'IOwinContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** on `GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()`.

Comment: In that case you are missing a reference somewhere - GetOwinContext is an extension method in the Microsoft.Owin namespace.

Make sure that you have Microsoft.Owin, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb and Microsoft.Owin.Security referenced.