# You can access GetOwinContext ().GetUserManager from ApiController class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I'm doing a project in a api, and I need to access from the **ApiController** class to:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync (model.UserName,model.Password...
```

but I have access neither
`HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()` 
nor

```
Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

Basically I need to check that the username and password are correct.

EDIT: I have reference to *microsoft.owin.host.SystemWeb*
and in ConfigureAuth `app.CreatePerOwinContext();`

Comment: Have you got `using System.Net.Http;` in the ApiController class?

Comment: Have you also installed NuGet Package `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`?

Comment: Yes I have  it. using System.Net.Http; and Nuget also It's a mvc project and web API.

Comment: what does it mean then "I have no access" ? Null ref? Compilation error or what?

Comment: Request.GetOwinContext() => System.Net.http.httpRequestMessage does not contain a definition for 'GetOwinContext' and no extension method 'GetOwinContext' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.httpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get UserManager from OwinContext in apicontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001245/cant-get-usermanager-from-owincontext-in-apicontroller)

Answer (score 2):

I've already solved, were missing from usings;

```
using System.Net.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

thank you everyone.