# ASP.NET MVC : currently logged in user - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display information of the current logged in user. In the `AccountController`, I added the following action method:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    //.......

    public ActionResult Profile()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if(userId == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "AccountControler");
        }
        else
        {
            ApplicationUser user = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId).Result;

            return View(user);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get the following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. _userManager was null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You forgot to set `_userManager` to something.

Answer (score 4):

_userManager would be null unless you're assigning it somewhere (and in the code you've included, you're not).

**Edit, to correspond to your edit**

Ideally, pass a UserManager instance into your controller constructor and let dependency injection handle it. You'd register the service in your Startup.cs.

If you're not up for that, you might want to browse this site for questions where people are having similar problems. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" isn't the problem, though. The problem is inside your UserManager getter.

**Maybe GetOwinContext() isn't available.** Check this question and similar ones: [Can't get UserManager from OwinContext in apicontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24001245/cant-get-usermanager-from-owincontext-in-apicontroller)

**Better Yet**

Learn to use your debugger! Place a breakpoint in your method and step through until it breaks. Mouse over the variables and see which one is null when you expect it not to be.

Comment: userId gets the right value.  _userManager is null. The rest is just generated code by Individual User Accounts feature